# Adding Button and label to UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Suppose I am developing or say prototyping an e-commerce app, where I have to show product list with their `price-tag(it will be UILabel)`, `product description(in UILabel)` and `buy(UIButton) button`. Product images will come from the web-server and it can be thousands.

So, I have chosen `UICollectionView` over `UITableview`, for more appealing looks. For buy button I have added `UIButton` in the cell of UICollectionView. But I can't make outlet from the `UILabel`, it says `illegal configuration`. So, am I going to right direction by choosing UICollectionView to display images coming from the back-end or there is any other way to do it efficiently?

I searched a lot but didn't found any good example to integrate `UICollectionView cell with buttons`.  For better understanding of my use case, I am attaching the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of my requirement]

Comment: make a custom class of collectionViewCell to make an outlet for cell or use tag property

Comment: Ok Captain, i can use the tag property...one more thing, is it the right and efficient way?

Comment: ok...ll give it try and come back to you, if any issue comes. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class for your cell and to handle your button's event create a delegate in it and handle it there.

```
@protocol CellDelegate

- (void) action;

@end

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CellDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;

@end
```

Comment: ok KP_G, i'll try and accept your answer when done. But i think `tag` approach will be better, cause i am able to achieve button functionality without using custom cell.

Comment: @KunalKumar actually, you should avoid using tags for such purposes, since you are making your action dependent on the value you give in IB.  But sure, if it serves your purpose... Well & good. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate class(with xib)for the cell you are using in your collectionView.

See this tutorial, will assist you in subclassing collection view cell.

http://sledgedev.com/build-a-custom-uicollectionviewcell/

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITableView` with static cells. So you can make design in `XIB` and your `IBOutlet` connections. (Note that static cells only support for `UITableViewController`)